# What it the best way to implement an Advanced Search form?

Tags: php, sql, search

Currently my application has an Advanced Search form, which is uses Ajax/php to query the db. My form fields are like:
Name, ID, Level, Class

So if user enter Level and class, it would display all students with same level and class... and so on.

Now I would like to improve it to allow user choose between AND/OR, for example, he wants to search for students with same name but either in level a or class a.

```
select * from table where name like name AND (level == level OR class == class)
```

What is the best way to accomplish that? Is there any technique or something similar to Solr and Hibernate Search ?

Comment: Why not just [edit your original question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16379692/edit)? It is possible for a question to be re-opened. You don't have to post a new question...